# How do I filter through nested JSON data in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I need to filter through a nested JSON array in AngularJS. The JSON structure looks like this:

```
articles_data: [{
    title: 'Bigfoot Afoot',
    tags: ['True stories', 'forests'],
    description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dapibus mi at nulla finibus pretium. Curabitur auctor lacus vitae varius viverra. Sed pharetra varius sapien, id hendrerit ipsum lacinia placerat. Morbi vitae neque ipsum. Curabitur sem neque, iaculis vel nisl a, condimentum commodo arcu. Morbi nec urna efficitur, tempor nisl a, aliquet felis. Ut non est massa. Proin eget purus est. Integer eu nisi sed nisi maximus sodales. Duis finibus turpis a velit consectetur, luctus eleifend metus scelerisque. Pellentesque suscipit iaculis purus vel convallis.",
    category: 'Bigfoot'
  },
  {
    title: 'Lockness Sighted!',
    tags: ['Sightings', 'Lakes'],
    description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dapibus mi at nulla finibus pretium. Curabitur auctor lacus vitae varius viverra. Sed pharetra varius sapien, id hendrerit ipsum lacinia placerat. Morbi vitae neque ipsum. Curabitur sem neque, iaculis vel nisl a, condimentum commodo arcu. Morbi nec urna efficitur, tempor nisl a, aliquet felis. Ut non est massa. Proin eget purus est. Integer eu nisi sed nisi maximus sodales. Duis finibus turpis a velit consectetur, luctus eleifend metus scelerisque. Pellentesque suscipit iaculis purus vel convallis.",
    category: 'Nessy'
  },
  {
    title: 'Jacktalopes Everywhere',
    tags: ['Rabbits', 'cities'],
    description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dapibus mi at nulla finibus pretium. Curabitur auctor lacus vitae varius viverra. Sed pharetra varius sapien, id hendrerit ipsum lacinia placerat. Morbi vitae neque ipsum. Curabitur sem neque, iaculis vel nisl a, condimentum commodo arcu. Morbi nec urna efficitur, tempor nisl a, aliquet felis. Ut non est massa. Proin eget purus est. Integer eu nisi sed nisi maximus sodales. Duis finibus turpis a velit consectetur, luctus eleifend metus scelerisque. Pellentesque suscipit iaculis purus vel convallis.",
    category: 'Jacktalope'
  }
]
```

I am looping through with an `ng-repeat`:

```
<div class="col-md-7 articles">
  <section>
    <div class="card filter" ng-repeat="article in articles.articlemanager.articles track by $index">
      <div class="card-header">
        {{article.title}} &nbsp;<small>{{article.tags.join()}}</small>
        <span class="badge badge-{{article.category}} float-right">{{article.category}}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>
          {{article.description}}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

This displays my articles but I need to go a step further and filter them by name or by tag:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="filterName">Filter by name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filterName">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="filterTags">Filter by tags</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filterTags">
  </div>
</form>
```

I don't really know how to use filters in AngularJS but I'm on a time crunch and could use the help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="card filter" ng-repeat="article in articles.articlemanager.articles | filter : filterName | filter: filterTags track by $index">
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `| filter` after your `ng-repeat` and save it to a `ng-model` which is added to the `<input>`. You can add more `filter`s by just piping more with `|`. You can learn more about filters [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

```js
var app = angular.module("DummyApp", []);

var DummyController = function($scope) {
  $scope.articles_data = [{
      title: 'Bigfoot Afoot',
      tags: ['True stories', 'forests'],
      description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dapibus mi at nulla finibus pretium. Curabitur auctor lacus vitae varius viverra. Sed pharetra varius sapien, id hendrerit ipsum lacinia placerat. Morbi vitae neque ipsum. Curabitur sem neque, iaculis vel nisl a, condimentum commodo arcu. Morbi nec urna efficitur, tempor nisl a, aliquet felis. Ut non est massa. Proin eget purus est. Integer eu nisi sed nisi maximus sodales. Duis finibus turpis a velit consectetur, luctus eleifend metus scelerisque. Pellentesque suscipit iaculis purus vel convallis.",
      category: 'Bigfoot'
    },
    {
      title: 'Lockness Sighted!',
      tags: ['Sightings', 'Lakes'],
      description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dapibus mi at nulla finibus pretium. Curabitur auctor lacus vitae varius viverra. Sed pharetra varius sapien, id hendrerit ipsum lacinia placerat. Morbi vitae neque ipsum. Curabitur sem neque, iaculis vel nisl a, condimentum commodo arcu. Morbi nec urna efficitur, tempor nisl a, aliquet felis. Ut non est massa. Proin eget purus est. Integer eu nisi sed nisi maximus sodales. Duis finibus turpis a velit consectetur, luctus eleifend metus scelerisque. Pellentesque suscipit iaculis purus vel convallis.",
      category: 'Nessy'
    },
    {
      title: 'Jacktalopes Everywhere',
      tags: ['Rabbits', 'cities'],
      description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dapibus mi at nulla finibus pretium. Curabitur auctor lacus vitae varius viverra. Sed pharetra varius sapien, id hendrerit ipsum lacinia placerat. Morbi vitae neque ipsum. Curabitur sem neque, iaculis vel nisl a, condimentum commodo arcu. Morbi nec urna efficitur, tempor nisl a, aliquet felis. Ut non est massa. Proin eget purus est. Integer eu nisi sed nisi maximus sodales. Duis finibus turpis a velit consectetur, luctus eleifend metus scelerisque. Pellentesque suscipit iaculis purus vel convallis.",
      category: 'Jacktalope'
    }
  ]
}

app.controller("DummyController", ["$scope", DummyController]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="DummyApp">
  <div ng-controller="DummyController">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="filterName">Filter by name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filterName" ng-model="filterName">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="filterTags">Filter by tags</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filterTags" ng-model="filterTag">
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="col-md-7 articles">
      <section>
        <div class="card filter" ng-repeat="article in articles_data | filter:filterName | filter:filterTag">
          <div class="card-header">
            {{article.title}} &nbsp;<small>{{article.tags.join()}}</small>
            <span class="badge badge-{{article.category}} float-right">{{article.category}}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p>
              {{article.description}}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your example works when I run it but when I apply that to my code I get arrors. See the full code here https://github.com/webface/Hanen

Answer (score 0):

Depending what you actually want but the easiest way when using ng-repeat is the filter function.

```
<li ng-repeat="x in names | orderBy:'FirstName'">
```

Here is the link to the documentation there are many options you can use.
[AngularJS Documentation filter function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)